# Are there any synonyms of "pair of pants" in topology?

Tags: general-topology, terminology

I used to know a term for [pair of pants](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pair_of_pants), but perhaps there is none. It looks like [this](https://plus.google.com/photos/113700290255174605295/albums/5771602186812908641/5771602190269286610) also.

Comment: I was amused to find that the wikipedia page for "Trousers" does, in fact, have your wikipedia page as a disambiguation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could call it a "pretzel", as shown on http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/surgery/zeeman.pdf.  I've also heard it called a "trophy".

Comment: it don't looks like pretzel, maybe it homeomorphic to it.

Comment: I guess there is no other name.

Comment: I have also heard (and used) trinion, in some conformal field theory papers (we often manipulate Riemann surfaces in 2d CFT).